# Trying to load JSON into d3 treemap without using a GET

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am using http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/ to attempt to incorporate a D3 treemap into Splunk.  However, it errors on the d3.JSON("flare.json") as it can't find the file.  I have tried putting the JSON array right into the js and calling root = JSON.parse(myjson), but then then it arrays with unexpected character JSON.parse.  If you look at the js from Bostick's page, you can see that I can't just remove the d3.JSON, because it calls back to the functions that actually render the treemap.

Do you have any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
renderResults: function($super, results) {

    if(!results) {
    this.resultsContainer.html('No content available.');
        return;
    }
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
        width = 960,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        formatNumber = d3.format(",d"),
        transitioning;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, width])
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, height])
        .range([0, height]);

    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d._children; })
        .sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; })
        .ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))
        .round(false);

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
        .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
        .style("margin.right", -margin.right + "px")
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

    var grandparent = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grandparent");

    grandparent.append("rect")
        .attr("y", -margin.top)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", margin.top);

    grandparent.append("text")
        .attr("x", 6)
        .attr("y", 6 - margin.top)
        .attr("dy", ".75em");

    var myjson = not including the actual array to save space

            root = JSON.parse(myjson); 




    d3.json("flare.json", function(root) { 
      initialize(root);
      accumulate(root);
      layout(root);
      display(root); 

      function initialize(root) {
        root.x = root.y = 0;
        root.dx = width;
        root.dy = height;
        root.depth = 0;
      } 

      // Aggregate the values for internal nodes. This is normally done by the
      // treemap layout, but not here because of our custom implementation.
      // We also take a snapshot of the original children (_children) to avoid
      // the children being overwritten when when layout is computed.
      function accumulate(d) {
        return (d._children = d.children)
            ? d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
            : d.value;
      }

      // Compute the treemap layout recursively such that each group of siblings
      // uses the same size (1×1) rather than the dimensions of the parent cell.
      // This optimizes the layout for the current zoom state. Note that a wrapper
      // object is created for the parent node for each group of siblings so that
      // the parent’s dimensions are not discarded as we recurse. Since each group
      // of sibling was laid out in 1×1, we must rescale to fit using absolute
      // coordinates. This lets us use a viewport to zoom.
      function layout(d) {
        if (d._children) {
          treemap.nodes({_children: d._children});
          d._children.forEach(function(c) {
            c.x = d.x + c.x * d.dx;
            c.y = d.y + c.y * d.dy;
            c.dx *= d.dx;
            c.dy *= d.dy;
            c.parent = d;
            layout(c);
          });
        }
      }

      function display(d) {
        grandparent
            .datum(d.parent)
            .on("click", transition)
          .select("text")
            .text(name(d));

        var g1 = svg.insert("g", ".grandparent")
            .datum(d)
            .attr("class", "depth");

        var g = g1.selectAll("g")
            .data(d._children)
          .enter().append("g");

        g.filter(function(d) { return d._children; })
            .classed("children", true)
            .on("click", transition);

        g.selectAll(".child")
            .data(function(d) { return d._children || [d]; })
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "child")
            .call(rect);

        g.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "parent")
            .call(rect)
          .append("title")
            .text(function(d) { return formatNumber(d.value); });

        g.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".75em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
            .call(text);

        function transition(d) {
          if (transitioning || !d) return;
          transitioning = true;

          var g2 = display(d),
              t1 = g1.transition().duration(750),
              t2 = g2.transition().duration(750);

          // Update the domain only after entering new elements.
          x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
          y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

          // Enable anti-aliasing during the transition.
          svg.style("shape-rendering", null);

          // Draw child nodes on top of parent nodes.
          svg.selectAll(".depth").sort(function(a, b) { return a.depth - b.depth; });

          // Fade-in entering text.
          g2.selectAll("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

          // Transition to the new view.
          t1.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 0);
          t2.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 1);
          t1.selectAll("rect").call(rect);
          t2.selectAll("rect").call(rect);

          // Remove the old node when the transition is finished.
          t1.remove().each("end", function() {
            svg.style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
            transitioning = false;
          });
        }

        return g;
      }

      function text(text) {
        text.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + 6; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) + 6; });
      }

      function rect(rect) {
        rect.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
            .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.dy) - y(d.y); });
      }

      function name(d) {
        return d.parent
            ? name(d.parent) + "." + d.name
            : d.name;
      }
    };

}
```

I am still not 100% sure how these two even are able to interact.  I have a little JavaScript experience, but no Python experience.  The way Splunk integrates all these scripts together is baffling.

```
import cherrypy
import controllers.module as module

import splunk, splunk.search, splunk.util, splunk.entity
import json
from splunk.appserver.mrsparkle.lib import jsonresponse
import lib.util as util
import lib.i18n as i18n

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('splunk.module.TreeMap1')

import math
import cgi

class TreeMap1(module.ModuleHandler):

def generateResults(self, host_app, client_app, sid, count=1000, 
        offset=0, entity_name='results'):

    count = max(int(count), 0)
    offset = max(int(offset), 0)
    if not sid:
        raise Exception('TreeMap1.generateResults - sid not passed!')

    try:
        job = splunk.search.getJob(sid)
    except splunk.ResourceNotFound, e:
        logger.error('TreeMap could not find job %s. Exception: %s' % (sid, e))
        return _('<p class="resultStatusMessage">Could not get search data.</p>')

    dataset = getattr(job, entity_name)[offset: offset+count]

    outputJSON = {}
    for i, result in enumerate(dataset):
        tdict = {}
        tdict[str(result.get('itemName', None))] = str(result.get('totalCPU', None))
        name = str(result.get('itemCat', None))
        if name not in outputJSON:
            outputJSON[name] = dict()
        outputJSON[name].update(tdict)

    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/json'
    return json.dumps(outputJSON, sort_keys=True)

def render_json(self, response_data, set_mime='text/json'):
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = set_mime

    if isinstance(response_data, jsonresponse.JsonResponse):
        response = response_data.toJson().replace("</", "<\\/")
    else:
        response = json.dumps(response_data).replace("</", "<\\/")

    return ' ' * 256  + '\n' + response
```

Answer (score 1):

D3's `d3.JSON(url, ...)` literally performs a GET request and attempts to parse the response as JSON*; it is similar to jQuery's `$.getJSON(url, ...)`. If you already have the JSON necessary to construct the tree map, just ignore the call altogether and go straight to the callback. **If you already have an array/object, you don't need `JSON.parse`**; JSON.parse turns a valid JSON string into an array/object.

*See the documentation on [d3.json](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests) for more...

Along the same lines, if you already have the data, you can just use:

```
  ...

  var myJSON = [ ... ] //The actual array you're loading.
  initialize(myJSON);
  accumulate(myJSON);
  layout(myJSON);
  display(myJSON);

  ...
```

**However,** notice what you're actually doing in the code above. You're passing an *array* into `initialize` -- which appears to want an *object*:

```
  function initialize(root) { //Root in this case is myVar -- an ARRAY.
    root.x = root.y = 0;  //Arrays don't have fields. This is BAD.
    root.dx = width;
    root.dy = height;
    root.depth = 0;
  }
```

Thus, what you should do is figure out what type of structure `myJSON` should use.

---

If the error that you want to fix is actually that the "flare.json" file can't be found, then your problem is actually *server-side*. How are you serving the flare.json file? Try accessing it in your browser to make sure it is located where you think it is.

Comment: It didn't error, but the treemap still doesn't display.  I think this might be an issue with the associated python script, which is meant to handle the splunk search.

I would almost expect this to be the case, because I eventually don't want to use flare.json at all, but instead use the results of the splunk search to create the treemap.

Comment: Could you post the relevant Python code? The issue is agnostic of the fact that you don't want to use flare.json; the issue is that you are passing D3 what almost certainly is the wrong object. What is the exact structure of myJSON/flare.json?

Comment: That looks fine to me in terms of what you are returning (a JSON object), **but that is not what your code is requesting from the server.** Compare the format of myJSON and what the proper result should be (from `generateResults`); they are not the same. Do you have a URL bound to that function? If so, instead of using "frames.json," just use the URL instead.

Comment: Oh, sorry; I just noticed your comment that you don't have the pipeline complete yet. I would recommend that you integrate the pipeline so that you can send data from the server FIRST -- particularly because the data needs to be formatted in a particular way. What is the content of frames.json? Is that a sample output?

Comment: Assuming you mean flare.json, it can be seen here ( https://bitbucket.org/john2x/d3test/src/2ce4dd511244/d3/examples/data/flare.json ).  I am unsure how to get that pipeline in place, without the ability to understand what it wants.  I understand that the python takes the splunk search and returns a JSON (from what I can tell).  I just don't know how to feed those results into the js file.

The other reason I didn't get the pipeline in place first, is because I want to see that the TreeMap will actually render properly.

Comment: Notice that the contents of "flare.json" are NOT an array, but an object -- `[]` vs `{}`. If I were you, I would figure out why "flare.json" is not being found and fix that. Open up your Developer Tools (I recommend Chrome's) and see where the browser is searching.

Comment: Will do.  I would prefer to not worry about flare.json, if it just makes it harder.  As I mentioned, I am just trying to use flare.json to see the treemap.  I would prefer to use the results of the python script to populate the treemap, but I am not sure if the javascript will be able to do that in its current state.